# Optimizing select query with limit and order by

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

Following is my query:

`select * from table order by timestamp desc limit 10`

this takes too much time compared to

`select * from table limit 10`

How can I optimize the first query to get to near performance of second query.

UPDATE:  I don't have control over the db server, so can not index columns to gain performance.

Answer (score 4):

Create an index on `timestamp`.

Comment: Actually, I don't have control over the db server.  Sorry for not mentioning this in question.

Comment: @Nishan: then you can do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Quassnoi is correct -- you need an index on timestamp.

That said, if your timestamp field reasonably maps your primary key (e.g. a date_created or an invoice_date field), you can try this workaround:

```
select *
from (select * from table order by id desc limit 1000) as table
order by timestamp desc limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nishan is right. There is little you can do. If you do not need every column in the table you may gain a few milliseconds by explicitly asking for just the columns you need

Comment: What would be the default order of rows if I just did `select * from table`? If it was ordered based on timestamp I could avoid the `order by` clause.

Comment: There's no such thing as "default order of rows" in a SQL database. If you don't use `ORDER BY`, the query optimizer will return rows in whatever order it thinks is the fastest. That may change from run to run, as row counts change, statistics change, and so on.